# How to call data in batches from select statement and append into dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

I have a file with a sql statement that I am reading into python using `pyodbc`. The sql statement is just a select statement like so:

```
select distinct (columns) from table1
```

However the data I am calling is 30 million rows.

I can do this for smaller tables, and put the information in a dataframe.

Is there anyway to batch the select statement to pull only an X number of rows and append into a dataframe and keep doing this till the end of the 30million records?

code so far:

```
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import tinys3
import psycopg2
import pyodbc
from datetime import datetime
import uuid
import glob
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import time

startTime = datetime.now()

#reading in data for db
server = 'xxxx' 
database = 'xxx' 
username = 'xxx' 
password = 'xxxx' 
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER='+driver+';SERVER='+server+';PORT=xxx;DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
path = "path/to/folder"




for infile in glob.glob( os.path.join(path, '*.sql') ):
    with open(infile, 'r') as myfile:
        sql = myfile.read()
        print(sql)
        myfile.close()
        cursor.execute(sql)

        row = cursor.fetchall()
        columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
        columns = [element.lower() for element in columns]

        df = pd.DataFrame([tuple(t) for t in row])
        df.columns = columns
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [fetchmany function](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyodbc/wikis/Cursor.wiki#fetchmany):

> cursor.fetchmany([size=cursor.arraysize]) --> list
>
> Returns a list of remaining rows, containing no more than size rows,
>   used to process results in chunks. The list will be empty when there
>   are no more rows.
>
> The default for cursor.arraysize is 1 which is no different than
>   calling fetchone().
>
> A ProgrammingError exception is raised if no SQL has been executed or
>   if it did not return a result set (e.g. was not a SELECT statement).

This will allow you to pull data in chunks.

**Example of use:**

```
while True:
    three_rows = cursor.fetchmany(3)
    # every loop cycle, 3 rows are selected
    if not results:
        break;
    print(three_rows)
```

You could also use the fetchdone function, to process the data row by row.

> fetchone
>
> cursor.fetchone() --> Row or None
>
> Returns the next row or None when no more data is available.

Comment: would `cursor.fetchmany()` go where I have `row = cursor.fetchall()`?

Comment: @RustyShackleford I added an example. You cannot just replace fetchALL with fetchMANY, because you obviously need to call fetchmany one time per chunk, so, in a loop probably.

Comment: @RustyShackleford do you need additional information ?

Comment: just making the could work, I keep getting error `yield outside function error`, error on my end I believe

Comment: @RustyShackleford You dont need to use yield, I will modify the example